# What's the difference between fetchgraph and loadgraph in JPA 2.1?

Tags: java, jpa-2.1

How does `javax.persistence.fetchgraph` differ from `javax.persistence.loadgraph` when providing an EntityGraph hint to a JPA 2.1 query?  The documentation isn't really clear.

Answer (score 22):

When using `fetchgraph` all relationships are considered to be `lazy` regardless of annotation, and only the elements of the provided graph are loaded.  This particularly useful when running reports on certain objects and you don't want a lot of the stuff that's normally flagged to load via `eager` annotations.

If you want to eagerly load entities that are normally loaded via `lazy` annotation, you may use `loadgraph` to add entities to the query results that would normally be loaded later, thereby avoiding specific N+1 cases.  Relationships that were already flagged as `eager` will continue to be loaded as usual.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs001.htm